# Prevent KeyboardAvoidingView from causing content to overlap (React Native)?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I am trying to create a `KeyboardAvoidingView` area for a signup form. I have gotten the component to a place where the actual keyboard adjustment is decent on iOS and Android.

However, instead of adding more height to the bottom of the view and scrolling up, the `KeyboardAvoidingView` seems to be simply compressing the height.

Here is the resulting effect on Android:

**Before keyboard adjustment:**

[image]

**After keyboard adjustment:**

[image]

Here's the code for the component:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView keyboardVerticalOffset={20} behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : null} style={mainWithFooter.container}>
  <View style={mainWithFooter.main}>
    <Text style={material.display1}>Create Your Account</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={mainWithFooter.footer}>
    <Input
      placeholder='First name'
      onChangeText={t => updateSignupForm('firstName', t)}
    />
    <Input
      placeholder='Last name'
      onChangeText={t => updateSignupForm('lastName', t)}
    />
    <Input
      placeholder='Email'
      keyboardType='email-address'
      autoCapitalize='none'
      onChangeText={t => updateSignupForm('email', t)}
    />
    <Input
      placeholder='Password'
      secureTextEntry
      onChangeText={t => updateSignupForm('password', t)}
    />
    <Button
      text='Create Account'
      onPress={signup}
      primary
      disabled={!signupFormIsValid}
      block
    />
  </View>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

And the styles:

```
export default StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 30,
    minHeight: '100%',
  },
  main: {
    flex: 1,
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  footer: {
    width: '100%',
    flex: 0,
  },
})
```

How can I fix this, so that the content does not overlap?

Comment: Did you try to put the View mainWithFooter.main outside the KeyboardAvoidingView ?

Comment: @RafaelMotta Yes, I tried that first. No difference.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. I wrapped the *children* of `KeyboardAvoidingView` in a `View` component and then set the `minHeight` of that component using `Dimennsions.get('window').height`. See your example below:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView keyboardVerticalOffset={20} behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : null} style={mainWithFooter.container}>
    <View style={mainWithFooter.wrapper}> ** <-- wrapper here. **
      <View style={mainWithFooter.main}>
        <Text style={material.display1}>Create Your Account</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={mainWithFooter.footer}>
        <Input
          placeholder='First name'
          onChangeText={t => updateSignupForm('firstName', t)}
        />
       ...
      </View>
    </View>
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Then the style:

```
const windowHeight: Dimensions.get('window').height;

export default StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    minHeight: windowHeight,
  },
    ...
});
```

You may need to add additional necessary styles such as `flex` etc. to the wrapper.